# angularjs Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-scope

I am getting error @ LINE NO 8193 from angularjs (V1.2.16) in IE8

```
/**
   * Callback registered to $httpBackend():
   *  - caches the response if desired
   *  - resolves the raw $http promise
   *  - calls $apply
   */
  function done(status, response, headersString, statusText) {
    if (cache) {
      if (isSuccess(status)) {
        cache.put(url, [status, response, parseHeaders(headersString), statusText]);
      } else {
        // remove promise from the cache
        cache.remove(url);
      }
    }

    resolvePromise(response, status, headersString, statusText);
    if (!$rootScope.$$phase) $rootScope.$apply(); // Error getting @ this line
  }
```

Here is the html that is i am using

`<div id="unHandledExceptionDiv" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3>{{'fatalExceptionDialogTitle' | i18next:model }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <span id="unhandledExceptionMessage">{{unHandledExceptionMessage}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary login_button" value="OK" ng-click="onUnhandleExceptionDialogOk()" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

Error "Unable to get property 'apply' of undefined or null reference"

did anyone come across this error ?

-Yogesh

Comment: AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core team does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or earlier.  Might be a losing battle with ie8.  Something to consider.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an error with Angular. It is something in your code (maybe a callback for an `$http` method).

Comment: Have you definitely injected `$rootScope` into the controller, or whatever is calling `$rootScope.$apply` ?

Comment: Actually i am using "angular strap" 
i have written like this
loginService.unHandledErrorDialog = modalService.Dialog({ scope: $scope, templateUrl: "Directives/ErrorControl/loginErrorHandler.tpl.html", show: false });
 $scope.$on('exception', function (e, cause) {
                        var errorMessage = cause.message ? cause.message : cause;
$scope.unHandledExceptionMessage = errorMessage;
                        //loginService.applyScope($scope);
                        modalService.show(loginService.unHandledErrorDialog);
                    });
In that where do i need to add rootscope

Comment: while loading the mentioned template i am getting the above error

Comment: @user3249448: Why don't yu post the full stack trace ?

Comment: Call stack 
====================================================================
Anonymous function, loginMain.js, line 892  

wrappedCallback, angular.js, line 11322  

Anonymous function, angular.js, line 11405

$eval, angular.js, line 12412  

$digest, angular.js, line 12224  

$apply, angular.js, line 12516

done, angular.js, line 8204

completeRequest, angular.js, line 8412  

onreadystatechange, angular.js, line 8351

Comment: @user3249448: How does the anonymous function in `loginMain.js`, line 892, look like ?